# Why 食べるなり rather than 食べたなり?

Tags: grammar, tense

> 私は作った料理を一口**食べるなり**、父は変な顔をした

The action 'to eat' is before the obvious change on the father. In the clause '父は変な顔をした', the verb changes into た形. Why is the front phrase '食べるなり', not '食べたなり’?

Comment: One theory suggests that that なり is originally a noun that means "appearance". It's still difficult to grasp how it has changed to the current meaning, though.

Answer (score 3):

> 例句： 私が作った料理を一口食べるなり、父は変な顔をした。

( 私が, not 私は)

[as soon as [he] ...]

For this one, you can just remember that this is like an idiom or a set-phrase and it's never *[食べたなり] or *[～したなり].

It uses the root form (dictionary form) of the verb: 食べるなり、～するなり ...

「～するやいなや」is a similar expression [が早いか versus や否や](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4916/16344)
「～するやいなや」also uses the root form of the verb.

This is related to the [relative tense] issue.  I hope to add some more material to this thread: 
[相対テンス -- ①ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買う。　②ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買った。　③ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買う。 ④ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買った。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39648/16344)