# What's the difference between かと思うか and 途端に?

Tags: grammar

I understand that both かと思うか and 途端に mean "as soon as something happen another thing happens as well". I see that their usage is different, especially when かと思うか is used with emotive verbs, however I still feel that I don't understand the difference. Maybe,it might be that I didn't fully understand かと思うか. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: it almost sounds as if you're mixing up two similar English expressions... "Just as I did X, Y happened."  and "Just as I thought"  .... or something. Can you give an example of the way you think these two expressions are used, so we can figure out where the confusion is?  Because 思う means "think" and I can't imagine a phrase using "think" that also works as an alternate way of saying "Just as/at once/mid-action" or any of the usages of  途端に...

Comment: It might help to read more about かと思う vs と思う [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29822)

Comment: Let's just start  saying that English is not my first language, so I may have expressed my duubt clearly. For example why in this sentence 最近は肌寒くなったかと思うと翌日には暖かくなったりする。Why 途端に cannot be used instead of かと思うか?

Comment: yeah, as I thought, you are mistaking かと思う's meaning in that sentence. @user27280 is right, their link will help you understand what かと思う actually means.  I think the reason you feel it has something to do with timing is only because of 翌日に that comes after it...

Comment: @Alex16 It is important to include the specific phrase that you are not understanding and as much source reference as you are comfortable with, as context is very important and can be the difference between an easy/satisfactory answer and a convoluted/irrelevant answer. In this case, と思うと is quite different from と思うか. One particle can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think 「かと思うか」is not an established phrase, but 「思う」is often used with [「が[早]{はや}いか」or「や[否]{いな}や」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4916/%E3%81%8C%E6%97%A9%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B-versus-%E3%82%84%E5%90%A6%E3%82%84?rq=1) .
「...[思]{おも}うが[早]{はや}いか」 (meaning as soon as I thought something) indicates  virtually the same thing as 「思った[途端]{とたん}に」.
So it might be「[思]{おも}うが[早]{はや}いか」that you had in mind.
The example sentence in your comment:
[最近]{さいきん}は[肌寒]{はだざむ}くなったかと[思]{おも}うと[翌日]{よくじつ}には[暖]{あたた}かくなったりする。
is about another topic. The particle 「と」 in 「思うと」 is a conjunctive particle and is working like "whenever" in English.
The 「と」 indicates one thing always follow the other thing ,and this sequence of events occurs repeatedly. It is combining with other words to suggest a sense of immediacy but not exactly working like "as soon as" by itself.